# filter an form library list view web part with multiple values in a column coming using a Current User Filter

Tags: web-part, infopath

I need to filter an form library list view web part with multiple values in a column using a Current User Filter web part as a provider. however I was unsuccesful since it only works for the first value. I also tried to separate the values with semi colon but it did not work either.

any ideas?